# How do I create an Operator which requires the user to select a text buffer before it does any work?

Tags: operator

I have an idea for an operator that uses the contents of a text buffer as part of its input (for a trivial case, imagine an operator that creates a polyline from `[ f(q) for q in range(0,100) ]` where f is defined in python inside the text buffer) .

I am not sure how to even begin to code this operator.  I can't think of any existing operators that use text buffers as input.  Without knowing which text buffer has the data, the operator can't do any work.

How can an Operator prompt the user to select a text buffer?